# Reloading flash game + disabling timers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My friend and I have to create a flash game from scratch for school. The game runs fine until we reach the game over screen. I've been trying to disable the object timers so that the powerups and enemies coming onto the screen, with no luck. 
Also, when I try to restart the game it starts where the previous played game has ended. With the same speed, enemies etcetera. Is there any way to reset it?

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.ui.*;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        private var level:uint = 0;
        private var lives:int = 0;
        private var score:uint = 0
        private var speed:uint = 10;

        public function Main()
        {
            stop();
        }

        public function verwijderObstacles():void
        {

            if(getChildByName("obstacle_mc") != null){
                mcObstacle(getChildByName("obstacle_mc")).destroy();
            }
        }

        public function verwijderPowerups():void
        {
            if(getChildByName("score_mc") != null){
                mcScore(getChildByName("score_mc")).destroy();
            }
        }

        public function verwijderLife():void
        {
            if(getChildByName("life_mc") != null){
                mcLife(getChildByName("life_mc")).destroy();
            }
        }


        public function initGame()
        {
            stage.focus = stage;
            var gravity:Number = 3;
            var jumping:Boolean = false;
            var jumpPower:Number = 0;
            var score_mc:MovieClip = new mcScore();
            var obstacle_mc:MovieClip = new mcObstacle();

            if(!contains(score_mc))
            {
                var scoreTimer:Timer = new Timer(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) * 1000 ,1);
                scoreTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, spawnScore);
                scoreTimer.start();
            }
            if(!contains(obstacle_mc))
            {
                var obstacleTimer:Timer = new Timer(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2) * 1000 ,1);
                obstacleTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, spawnObstacle);
                obstacleTimer.start();
            }
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, scrollBackground);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, scrollClouds);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, jump);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveScore);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveObstacle);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitScore);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitObstacle);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkOverlap);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkGame);

            function scrollBackground(e:Event):void
            {
                if(!(getChildByName("background1_mc") == null) && !(getChildByName("background2_mc") == null))
                {
                    background1_mc.x -= speed;
                    background2_mc.x -= speed;
                    if(background1_mc.x <= -background1_mc.width)
                    {
                        background1_mc.x = background2_mc.x + background2_mc.width;
                    }
                    else if(background2_mc.x <= -background2_mc.width)
                    {
                        background2_mc.x = background1_mc.x + background1_mc.width;
                    }
                }
            }

            function scrollClouds(e:Event):void
            {
                if(!(getChildByName("clouds1_mc") == null) && !(getChildByName("clouds2_mc") == null))
                {
                    var cloudSpeed = speed / 5;
                    clouds1_mc.x -= cloudSpeed;
                    clouds2_mc.x -= cloudSpeed;

                    if(clouds1_mc.x <= -clouds1_mc.width)
                    {
                        clouds1_mc.x = clouds2_mc.x + clouds2_mc.width;
                    }
                    else if(clouds2_mc.x <= -clouds2_mc.width)
                    {
                        clouds2_mc.x = clouds1_mc.x + clouds1_mc.width;
                    }
                }
            }

            function jump(e:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
                {
                    if(jumping != true)
                    {
                        jumpPower = -30;
                        jumping = true;
                        player_mc.gotoAndPlay(46);
                    }
                }   
            }

            function update(e:Event):void
            {
                if(jumping)
                {
                    player_mc.y += jumpPower;
                    jumpPower += gravity;

                    if(player_mc.y >= 320)
                    {
                        jumping = false;
                        player_mc.y = 320;
                        player_mc.gotoAndPlay(61);
                    }
                }
            }
            function spawnScore(e:TimerEvent):void
            {
                var randomNumber:Number = Math.round(Math.random());
                addChild(score_mc);
                score_mc.name = "score_mc";
                if(randomNumber == 0)
                {
                    score_mc.x = 800;
                    score_mc.y = 240;
                }
                else
                {
                    score_mc.x = 800;
                    score_mc.y = 30;
                }
            }
            function spawnObstacle(e:TimerEvent):void
            {
                addChild(obstacle_mc);
                obstacle_mc.x = 800;
                obstacle_mc.y = 240;
                obstacle_mc.name = "obstacle_mc";
            }

            function moveScore(e:Event):void
            {
                score_mc.x -= speed;
                if(!(getChildByName("score_mc") == null))
                {
                    if(score_mc.x < -86)
                    {
                        removeChild(getChildByName("score_mc"));
                        var scoreTimer:Timer = new Timer(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) * 1000 ,1);
                        scoreTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, spawnScore);
                        scoreTimer.start();
                    }
                }
            }
            function moveObstacle(e:Event):void
            {
                obstacle_mc.x -= speed;
                if(!(getChildByName("obstacle_mc") == null))
                {
                    if(obstacle_mc.x < -72)
                    {
                        removeChild(getChildByName("obstacle_mc"));
                        var obstacleTimer:Timer = new Timer(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) * 1000 ,1);
                        obstacleTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, spawnObstacle);
                        obstacleTimer.start();
                    }
                }
            }

            function hitScore(e:Event):void
            {
                if(!(getChildByName("score_mc") == null) && !(getChildByName("player_mc") == null))
                {
                    if (player_mc.hitTestObject(score_mc))
                    {
                        removeChild(getChildByName("score_mc"));
                        var scoreTimer:Timer = new Timer(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) * 1000 ,1);
                        scoreTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, spawnScore);
                        scoreTimer.start();
                        player_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
                        score++;
                        if(score == 1)
                        {
                            gauge_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
                        }
                        else if(score == 2)
                        {
                            gauge_mc.gotoAndPlay(16);
                        }
                        else if(score == 3)
                        {
                            gauge_mc.gotoAndPlay(31);
                        }
                        else if(score == 4)
                        {
                            gauge_mc.gotoAndPlay(46);
                        }
                        else if(score == 5)
                        {
                            gauge_mc.gotoAndPlay(61);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            function hitObstacle(e:Event):void
            {
                if(!(getChildByName("obstacle_mc") == null) && !(getChildByName("player_mc") == null))
                {
                    if(player_mc.hitTestPoint(obstacle_mc.x, obstacle_mc.y, true))
                    {
                        removeChild(getChildByName("obstacle_mc"));
                        var obstacleTimer:Timer = new Timer(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) * 1000 ,1);
                        obstacleTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, spawnObstacle);
                        obstacleTimer.start();
                        player_mc.gotoAndPlay(16);
                        lives--;
                        lives_txt.text = "x" + lives.toString();
                    }
                }
            }
            function checkOverlap(e:Event):void
            {
                if(obstacle_mc.hitTestObject(score_mc))
                {
                    if(!(getChildByName("score_mc") == null))
                    {
                        removeChild(getChildByName("score_mc"));
                        var scoreTimer:Timer = new Timer(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) * 1000 ,1);
                        scoreTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, spawnScore);
                        scoreTimer.start();
                    }
                }
            }


            function checkGame(e:Event):void
            {
                if(lives < 0)
                {
                    gaNaarGameOver();
                }
            }


        }
            private function gaNaarGameOver():void{

            //verwijderPowerups();
            //verwijderObstacles();
            gotoAndStop("gameover");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop a [Timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) you need to call [stop()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#stop%28%29) or [reset()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#reset%28%29). If you want it to go away completely you also want to remove the event listener from the timer and set it to null.

To do any of those things you will need a reference to the timer object. The easiest way to do that would be to create the timer as an instance variable of your Main class (rather than creating a local variable as you do now). If you don't want to do that you can also grab the reference to the Timer from inside the event handler by using the [currentTarget](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#currentTarget) property of the [TimerEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TimerEvent.html).